# Svelte showing warning for creating an app with unknown prop

Tags: svelte

I have a very basic Svelte app where I am displaying some super simple HTML, just starting.
In my dev tools console, though I see the following warning:

```
<App> was created with unknown prop 'name'
```

Why? This is my code in `app.svelte`:

```
<script>
  import Modal from "./modal.svelte"
  import Product from "./product.svelte"

  const products = [
    {
      id: "1",
      productTitle: "Product Title 1",
      productPrice: 111.11,
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      productTitle: "Product Title 2",
      productPrice: 222.22,
    },
  ]
  let showModal = false

  const addToCart = e => {
    console.log(e.detail)
  }

  const deleteFromCart = e => {
    console.log(e.detail)
  }
</script>

{#each products as product (product.id)}
  <Product {...product} on:add-to-cart={addToCart} on:delete={deleteFromCart} />
{/each}

<button on:click={() => (showModal = true)}>Show Modal</button>

{#if showModal}
  <Modal>
    <h1 slot="header">Hi!</h1>

    <p>This works!</p>

    <button slot="footer">Confirm</button>
  </Modal>
{/if}
```

When I expand the warning in the dev tools console it tells me I am missing this name prop on line 24 in `app.svelte` where I actually have a `console.log` statement.

Comment: Have a look inside the `main.js` file where the app is created with `new App()` - is there a prop `name` set?

Comment: @Corrl Yes! Thank you so much! My Svelte setup was copied from another guy and I didn't  even knew he had added "name" in there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @Corrl suggested the issue was in `main.js`. Since I had copied my Svelte setup from another guy I didn't knew I hade this additional `props` in there:

```
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
        name: 'world'
    }
});

export default app;
```

I just removed the `props` config and the warning is gone.